# TempData key not found issue in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using TempData to pass success or failure message in view page.
When i deployed application for first time it works fine but when server gets  restarted/reboot I get an session  issue in TempData as like in below screenshot.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `services.AddDataProtection` in your ConfigureServices? Perhaps this is your issue https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/issues/184

Answer (score 0):

TempData is discarded after the next request completes. This is useful for one-time messages, such as form validation errors. The important thing to take note of here is that this applies to the next request in the session, so that request can potentially happen in a different browser window or tab.

`TempData` is generally used to paas the values between controllers.

You should use `ViewBag` or `ViewData` to pass the value from controller to a view.

like

```
ViewBag.YourKey = "Value"
```

on CSHTML

```
@if(ViewBag.YourKey!=null)
{
}
```

or with ViewData

```
ViewData["YourKey"] = "Value"
```

on CSHTML

```
@if(ViewData["YourKey"] !=null)
{
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Actually, no.  TempData is typically used to pass single use message information such as "Operation Successful" or similar.   It can be either across controllers, or just from controller to view.  Regardless, telling them to use a different mechanism doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Still doesn't address the issue.  Calling TempData with a key that doesn't exist shouldn't throw this exception, it should return null.

Comment: The default TempData indexer uses TryGetValue and returns null if it's not found.  See https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/ViewFeatures/TempDataDictionary.cs so this should not happen, regardless of whether or not it's the "appropriate" use.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Hi isn't tempdata used to pass values from one action to another subsequent action pardon me if i am wrong but can tempdata be used in view ???

Comment: @RAHULSR - Yes, of course TempData can be used in a view.  It can also be used as you suggest.  By Default, TempData is stored in session, but as of the latest ASPNET-MVC core 2.0 builds, it's storing it in a cookie instead.  Regardless, TempData can be used anywhere in an asp.net-mvc app.  ViewData/Bag cannot be used across controller instances because it uses HttpContext.Items, which is based on the Request.